# heroku router timeout/interrupt causing lost responses

Tags: heroku, jax-rs, rabbitmq, router, amqp

I have what appears to be a race condition related to losing responses coming from my heroku web service.

The heroku router delivers the request to the web service, the web service processes the request and returns a response, but in the interim the heroku router fails the request, either due to client (interrupt) or backend timeout.

The problem is that the web service request processing changed state on the backend and expected to send the state change to the client in the body of the response.  The response never gets to the client, therefore the state change is lost forever.

The state change in my case happens to be the delivery and removal of a message from a RabbitMQ message queue.  The web service request handler pops the request from the RabbitMQ queue, but it fails to reach the client and is never heard of again.

I could implement my own client-based message ACK system to mitigate this.  However, I suspect that some of you might have a better solution regarding how to deal with ensuring that the responses get to the client.  Is there any callback that I can use on my web service to determine if the response was lost?  FWIW my web service is a JAX-RS service running embedded Jetty.

Thanks!